# Iterate with for loop to get silhouette_score

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Given small data frame:

```
preference_values = 

Column_name
-20.0
-19.7
...
-19.4
 19.1
```

I want to calculate `silhouette_score` with every value of data above

```
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation

af = AffinityPropagation(preference=-20.0, affinity='precomputed').fit(X) # where X is the similarity matrix 
cluster_centers_indices = af.cluster_centers_indices_
labels = af.labels_
n_clusters = len(np.unique(labels))
n_cluster_list.append(n_clusters)

from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples, silhouette_score

silhouette_score(frechet, labels, metric="precomputed") # frechet is a Frechet distance matrix calculated before
```

How to do it in a loop? I need to avoid putting every value of "`preference_values`" 1 by 1

### UPDATED

I want:

```
af = AffinityPropagation(preference=-20.0, affinity='precomputed').fit(X)
af = AffinityPropagation(preference=-19.7, affinity='precomputed').fit(X)
...
af = AffinityPropagation(preference=-19.4, affinity='precomputed').fit(X)
af = AffinityPropagation(preference=-19.1, affinity='precomputed').fit(X)
```

And store all results in a new dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to get the labels for the different preference values. From there you can print the values.

```
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation

for k in preference_values:
    af = AffinityPropagation(preference=k).fit(X)
    labels = af.labels_
    score = silhouette_score(X, labels, metric="precomputed")
    print("Preference: {0}, Silhouette score: {1}".format(k,score))
```

Comment: updated comment: I got the results. Just one question, I get only one number, but not the list of the numbers with every value of "preferences_values"

Comment: I now printed the silhouette score for every preferences_value. You can save them in a dictionary / pandas dataframe so you can have an overview.

Comment: I still get 1 value even with pandas. Can you assist me?

Comment: You know that silhouette_score is only one number right? I think you want to get something else.

Comment: Let me explain. In my question, in the part of `af=...preference=-20.0`. I want to put every number in `preference_values` and get number and store them somewhere. Like `preference=-20.0` - `0.13`, then `preference=-19.7` - 0.24, then `preference=-19.4`. I will update my question to make it clear